# Rewrite URL in PHP with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The web server is Apache. I want to rewrite URL so a user won't know the actual directory. For example: 
The original URL:

> ```
> http://www.example.com/en/piecework/piecework.php?piecework_id=11
> ```

Expected URL:

> ```
> http://piecework.example.com/en/11
> ```

How to achieve it with [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a rewrite rule (should be similar to this):

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/en/piecework/(.*)piecework_id=([0-9]+)(.*) piecework.mydomainname.com/en/$3
```

and put it in a .htaccess file under the main folder of you site

Full description of Rewrite rules here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

**EDIT**

Made a mistake in my rule, hopefully I corrected it.

Comment: How about `/en/piecework/piecework.php?soemthing=10&piecework_id=11&somethingelse=12`

Comment: Thankyou for pointing out the mistake. @Steven $2 means the second group of the reg-ex that you got from parsing the string with this rule ie.: the second (.*) in fact what you need is ([0-9]+) which is the third group referenced by $3

Comment: I have specify the rules(RewriteRule ^/(.*)/en/piecework/(.*)piecework_id=([0-9]+)(.*) piecework.mydomainname.com/en/$3) in .htaccess(in my site root), but when I access piecework.mydomainname.com/en/11, I got "Object not found".What's wrong?

Comment: Have you enabled .htaccess files in Apache configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

I found a fairly well written crash course in doing so here: 
http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/guide-url-rewriting

You'll need to specify the rules in .htaccess (in your site root).

Comment: I have specify the rules(RewriteRule ^/(.*)/en/piecework/(.*)piecework_id=([0-9]+)(.*) piecework.mydomainname.com/en/$3) in .htaccess(in my site root), but when I access http://piecework.mydomainname.com/en/11, I got "Object not found".

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www)([^.]+)\.mydomainname\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(w+)/(\d+)$ /$1/%1/%1.php?%1_id=$2 [L]
```

Comment: I have specified the rules(RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www)([^.]+)\.mydomainname\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(w+)/(\d+)$ /$1/%1/%1.php?%1_id=$2 [L]
) in .htaccess(in my site root), but when I access piecework.mydomainname.com/en/11, I got "Object not found".What's wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I've made a misprint. Try it like this:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www)([^.]+)\.mydomainname\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\d+)$ /$1/%1/%1.php?%1_id=$2 [L]