# .htaccess with mod_rewrite for PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rewrite URL in PHP with mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460851/rewrite-url-in-php-with-mod-rewrite)

I'm developing a job portal for our local city and its been developed using PHP and MySQL. I have included various functionalists into that like search by city and search by experience level and search by industry type and finally by dates.

I have an URL like this:

```
http://example.com/job_details.php?id=hj11&location=Mumbai&job=System+Administrator&company=Exa+India+Pvt+Ltd
```

I tried many ways to attain the end result what i expected. but its not happening for me..:-(

I'm looking for something like this,

```
http://example.com/jobs-in-mumbai/Exa-India-Pvt-Ltd/
```

Comment: Maybe this could help? - http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/htaccess-files-for-the-rest-of-us/?search_index=4

Comment: Did you mean you want to rewrite an URL as given in first example to a "beauty" URL like given in the second example using mod_rewrite?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rewrite URL in PHP with mod\_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460851/rewrite-url-in-php-with-mod-rewrite); http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188225/htaccess-mod-rewrite and the many other ones you can find in the related column on the right as well as http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+.htaccess+mod_rewrite+nice+url+howto

Answer (score 0):

You also need to put your id in the URL. So the URL will be:

```
http://example.com/jobs-in-mumbai/Exa-India-Pvt-Ltd/Mumbai/hj11
```

First of all, create a text file with file name: ".htaccess" and place that in the home folder (public home) of your server.

Place the given code in your htaccess file. Upload the file.

Code for converting the given URL to the URL specified above is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ job_details.php?id=$4&location=$3&job=$1&company=$2 [L]
```

Please try and let me know. Place the .htaceess to the same folder where job_details.php is placed. I assume this is in public home folder.